# Microsoft.Graph Nuget - 'DeltaResponse' is obsolete

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I have upgraded my Nuget package Microsoft.Graph in .net core 8 from version 5.28.0 to 5.42.0 and am getting the following warnings:

- 'DeltaResponse' is obsolete: 'This class is obsolete. Use {TypeName} instead.'
- 'DeltaRequestBuilder.GetAsync(Action<RequestConfiguration<DeltaRequestBuilder.DeltaRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters>>?, CancellationToken)' is obsolete: 'This method is obsolete. Use {TypeName} instead.'

In the following code:

```
        public string GetMailFromUserMailbox(string upn, string mailbox, Func<Message, bool> iterator, string? delta = null)
        {
            var messages = new List<Message>();

            DeltaRequestBuilder drb;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(delta))
                drb = new DeltaRequestBuilder(delta, Client.RequestAdapter);
            else
            {
                var mailboxId = GetUserMailBoxId(upn, mailbox);
                drb = Client.Users[upn].MailFolders[mailboxId].Messages.Delta;
            }

            var t = drb.GetAsync();
            t.Wait();

            var pageIterator = PageIterator<Message, DeltaResponse?>.CreatePageIterator(
                Client,
                t.Result ?? new DeltaResponse(),
                iterator
            );
            var pt = pageIterator.IterateAsync();
            pt.Wait();

            return pageIterator.Deltalink;
        }
```

The warning isn't very helpful in identifying the replacement class, has anyone any information on what the replacement method is to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, some weird bug in the latest version of SDK. Until it will be fixed:

- replace `GetAsync` with `GetAsDeltaGetResponseAsync`
- replace `DeltaResponse` with `DeltaGetResponse`

Code:

```
public string GetMailFromUserMailbox(string upn, string mailbox, Func<Message, bool> iterator, string? delta = null)
{
    var messages = new List<Message>();

    DeltaRequestBuilder drb;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(delta))
        drb = new DeltaRequestBuilder(delta, Client.RequestAdapter);
    else
    {
        var mailboxId = GetUserMailBoxId(upn, mailbox);
        drb = Client.Users[upn].MailFolders[mailboxId].Messages.Delta;
    }

    var t = drb.GetAsDeltaGetResponseAsync();
    t.Wait();

    var pageIterator = PageIterator<Message, DeltaGetResponse?>.CreatePageIterator(
                Client,
                t.Result ?? new DeltaGetResponse(),
                iterator
            );
    var pt = pageIterator.IterateAsync();
    pt.Wait();

    return pageIterator.Deltalink;
}
```